# ListView scroll to coordinates

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I need to scroll list view to some point (e.g. I need to scroll 250px)

I tried next code

```
container.setAdapter(crewAdapter);
container.scrollTo(0, scroll);
```

So now it looks good. But when I start scroll by touch scrollview 'jump' to 0 and scroll by finger from top. How to solve it?

Comment: Where are you calling container.scrollTo(0, scroll);?

Comment: I call that code at onClickListener (on button click). But I also tried to call at onViewCreated. No chages.